# How can i load nested forms in extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have the simple form  with textfields and its working fine.

Now i have the requirement that user should be able add many tags in the form.

The form is hardcoded with fields.

then i need section called tags where by default i will have single textbox and add button so that user can add more tags by typing.

I am thinking of using tags in separate forms but i am not sure how to do it

Any ideas please

Comment: add a input box and a button , and on it's click you can add as many fields as you like

Comment: but how can i send array to server when submitting. do i need to have same name for text box to send as array??

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/vajrakumar/L6gL7/2/) is a simple JSFidle in ExtJS 4.2.0 with dynamic adding of fields to formpanel and sending them on form submit to backend.

You can see that newly added fields getting sent to backend in fiddler.

And below is the code I have added to dynamically add fields on **Add Tags** Button Click :

```
   {
        xtype:'button',
        text:'Add Tags',
        width:100,
        handler:function(btn){
            formpanel.add({
                fieldLabel: 'New Item'+formpanel.items.length,     // formpanel is the name of the formpanel
                name: 'item'+formpanel.items.length,
                allowBlank: false
            });           
        }
    }
```

Comment: i want send items as array on server. will your function do that. i mean do need to have same name for all fields or different

Comment: Obviously All names will be different.   On form submit why can't you receive params in backend and generate an array out of it ?  In this case it will send each fields in body .

Comment: but @Satya on top told to have same name/id